# Including static library in makefile to create object file

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

I am currently having issues compiling an object file with a library.

```
myprog.o : $(USER_DIR)/src/myprog.c $(USER_DIR)/include/myprog.h $(USER_DIR)/lib/include/lib.h $(USER_DIR)/lib/lib.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -L$(USER_DIR)/lib -c $(USER_DIR)/src/myprog.c
```

The error I am getting is:

> lib.h: No such file or directory

In myprog.c, i include the library header as such:

```
#include <lib.h>
```

What is the correct way of linking the static library? (Is this good terminology? Do we link a static library or do we include it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I am currently having issues compiling an object file with a library" doesn't make sense. Compilation doesn't involve linking; object file is unlinked by definition, no libraries could affect that.

"lib.h: No such file or directory" on which phase? On compilation of `myprog.o`? What is actual compilation command? Is `-L$(USER_DIR)/lib` supposed to be `-I$(USER_DIR)/lib/include`?

`#include <lib.h>` better be `#include "lib.h"` if library is local to your program. If it is intended to be system-wide, then your way is correct (although name `lib` is.. too bad...)

Linking with library and including a header are completely different things; if you compiling object file, you cannot link with anything at all - because linker isn't involved in this process.